# api blueprint mson object with different values

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary, mson

I have a collection response which gives back an array of user objects and want to have different values for the user attributes without to create multiple user objects. Is there a way to do this?

```
# Group Users
## Users Collection [/api/v1/users]
### View Users [GET]

+ Request (application/vnd.api+json)

+ Headers

        Accept: application/vnd.api+json
        Authorization: Bearer JWT

+ Response 200 (application/vnd.api+json)
+ Attributes
  + meta (UsersMetaData)
  + data (array[User, User])
  + links (UserLinks)

# Data Structures
## User
+ type: users (string, required, fixed)
+ id: 1 (number, required)
+ attributes (UserAttributes, required)

## UserAttributes
+ email: test@test.com (string)
+ confirmed: false (boolean)
+ first_name: Melanie (string)
```

I don't want to create multiple user data structures to avoid an overload. But maybe there is a way to create sample arrays or something to do this in an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I just found out this way, in case someone has the same or similar question:

```
+ Response 200 (application/vnd.api+json)
+ Attributes
  + data (array)
      + (User)
          + attributes (UserAttributes)
              + email: `another@mail.com` (string)
              + confirmed: true (boolean)
      + (User)
          + attributes (UserAttributes)
              + first_name: Darth Vader
```

This way it is possible to rewrite just the attributes for each object without the need to create new ones.